# How can I access data from a DynamicFrame in nested json fields / structs with AWS Glue

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

Within a Map.apply() function on an AWS Glue DynamicFrame, I am trying to access data from a nested json column, but the DynamicFrame returned is empty.

Data structure:

```
root
|-- id: string
|-- policyId: string
|-- productId: string
|-- createdBy: string
|-- status: string
|-- data: struct
|    |-- values: struct
|    |    |-- G1Q1: string
|    |    |-- G1Q2: string
```

My code:

```
dyf1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="db",
    table_name="table1",
    transformation_ctx="table_1",
)

dyf1 = Unbox.apply(frame = dyf1, path = "data", format = "json")


def ProcessEntry(r):
    r["question1"] = r.data.values.G1Q1
    return r

dyf2 = Map.apply(frame = dyf1, f = ProcessEntry)


dyf2.toDF().show()
```

I have also tried to use this:

```
   r["question1"] = `r.data.values.G1Q1`
```

and this:

```
   r["question1"] = r["data.values.G1Q1"]
```

But the result which is returned is always empty instead of the full DataFrame with the additional column "question1" and the values from the nested column:

```
++
||
++
++
```

How can I correctly access the (nested) value in the (unboxed) DataFrame within the Map.apply() function?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out myself from this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html

It requires Python dictionary syntax:

```
r["question1"] = r["data"]["values"]["G1Q1"]
```